# Nginx: strip cookie from cached content

Tags: nginx, tomcat

Trying to replace Apache by Nginx as a web proxy in front of some Tomcat servers, dealing with `Set-Cookie JSESSIONID` is proving to be challenging.
Our Tomcat content is served with Cache-Control and Set-Cookie.

In Apache we can cache based purely on the Cache-Control by using the `CacheIgnoreHeaders Set-Cookie`... and here is the important part: the cached content is served without Set-Cookie so we're avoiding session leaks.
But in Nginx, `proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie` will fallback to `Cache-Control` to decide if a page should be cached... but the cached content is then served with that JSESSIONID.

Adding `proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie` removes the JSESSIONID from all served content, cached or not, meaning the whole site becomes stateless.

Comment: Ideally you should only have a session ID when there's an actual need for it (user logs in, user adds to cart, etc).

Comment: May be you need `proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_jsessionid;`?